# .NET C# Unexpected character '$'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I downloaded a .NET project and I'm trying to get it to build but I keep getting this same error on several different lines throughout the project. I'm not familiar with this notation. Can someone explain what it is? Am I missing a dependency?

```
Utilities.Log($"Could not resolve external entity ({absoluteUri})");
```

Thanks

Comment: Using an oudated language version? It is not like this was in there from the beginning.

Comment: $ is short-hand for String.Format and is used with string interpolations

It only works with C# 6 or later.
If you're getting an error check that you're not using a version of C# earlier than 6.

Read more about it [here][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: I found the problem. The project opened in VS 2013 for some reason and I didn't notice. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.